# Cheap VoIP Phone Recommendation

Tags: voip, sip, telephony, telephone

I'm looking for an inexpensive corded VoIP phone for my home office that supports SIP.  I've been using an old Cisco 7905G with SIP firmware but I'm concerned about security considering that it's REAAALLLY old and has been unsupported for several years.

I don't need anything fancy. Just a standard 1/2 line corded phone with basic features (hold, transfer, conference, etc). Ideally, I'd like to spend 50-60 bucks at most.  Used equipment is OK.

Any recommendations?

Thanks for your time and patience.

-M

Comment: Must it be corded? Why not cordless?

Comment: Product and service recommendations are specifically off topic for ServerFault (see point 4 in the NOT About section of the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at [snom](http://snom.com). i've read lot of good reviews of it. i bought recently two snom 300s but it's too early to comment on them.

avoid siements - i used s675 ip and s685 ip - with few handsets associated with base stations they hang every few weeks.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt feedback.  It's greatly appreciated.  I noticed that those phones typically retail for 100 - 200 bucks.  Anything cheaper?

Comment: I have used Siemens C475IP. They are good for home use, but not for businesses. Also: I had some lockups of base stations (no ping, lost SIP registration...).

Comment: i've bought snom300 few weeks ago in sweden for equivalent of ~120usd

Answer (score 0):

I have deployed hundreds of Atcom AT510 phones. They aren't fancy, but they just work. Also, take a look at Grandstream GXP-2000 but they are more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

I've deployed around 30,000 Grandstream BudgetTone 200s. They're very basic and work fine, including centralised management. Price point was around £ 30-40 sterling for small quantities (discounts down to low 20's for large quantities).

I've evaluated a "China Roby" phone which was cheaper, but I wasn't too impressed with it to be honest. I really like the Siemens Gigaset stuff, but that's cordless and more expensive - the later firmware is nice and solid.